# Get SharePoint list into Bot Framework Composer and use it

Tags: sharepoint, botframework

I am not able to find a simple way to **integrate** my SharePoint example list into my bot:

[image: SharePoint list]

I wonder if that is possible without another database like **Cosmos DB**.

What is the best practice to use such a SharePoint list and being able to search it in the Bot Framework Composer directly?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with reviewing a [Bot Framework sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples). I would think one using [the GRAPH api](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) would be a good start.

But essentially, you just need to authenticate the user (if not already done) and then make the correct calls (whatever is required for SharePoint api calls), during the appropriate location (`OnTurnAsync` or maybe `SimpleGraphClient` if using the above sample).